# Firebase rule auth.token.email is not working: "Simulated write denied"

Tags: firebase-authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtokenF

```
{
  "rules": {
    "c":{
      ".write":"newData.child('email').val()=== auth.token.email"
    },
   }
}
```

Always it showing  "Simulated write denied"
How to solve this problem ? Is there any mistake with my firebase rule

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the simulator when you get the error. Make sure it includes the information necessary to reproduce the problem, so: 1) the path you're writing to, 2) the data you're writing, 3) the auth token you specify.

Comment: I shared screenshot please check

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're not providing an email address in the authentication data.

When you select a provider, the simulator shows the exact `auth.token` payload that it will use. For the `Google` provider my Auth token payload looks like this:

[image: Auth.token for Google provider]

The simulator takes the literal JSON that is shown in here, and uses it as `auth.token`.

```
{
  "provider": "google",
  "uid": "27e08474-4e33-460d-ba92-ba437c6aa962"
}
```

Since there is no email provided, your rules (correctly) fail.

For testing this scenario, you'll want to switch to a custom provider, so that you can specify your own auth token *with* an email property:

[image: Custom auth.token with email property]

Comment: it seems this is the correct answer. The email property is missing from the custom token payload.