# Adding string in firebase rules push Id and checking equality

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How does one add a string to a specified branchname of the database and check it's equality to the email of the user that is trying to access it in Firebase rules. So for I have tried the following rules but it doesn't work.

```
"usersetdata":{
  "$uname":{
    ".read" : "$uname + '@domain.xta' == auth.token.email",
    ".write" : "$uname + '@domain.xta' == auth.token.email"
  }
}
```

However if I use custom token in the simulations with the email specified firebase allows read access. Am I missing something or does firebase send the email in the token in a different way?

$uname represents the local part of the address (user1 in user1@domain.xta).

Answer (score 2):

**Check these link:**

- [Firebase rule auth.token.email is not working: "Simulated write denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878527/firebase-rule-auth-token-email-is-not-working-simulated-write-denied)

  ```
                              or
  ```
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken

Comment: feel free to comment for further help

Comment: Will do as suggested in the link perhaps the email is not being sent with the database access request. Need to look into it.