# Want to allow only single domain (@example.com) email for sign-up in firebase not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have written one rule on firebase to restrict other domain sign up but it's not working and due to that anyone can able to sign-up with any domain.

**My Rule On Firebase:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email.endsWith('@example.com');
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

Maybe some issues in my rule or I am missing something.

Help me in correcting the above rule to restrict sign up with other domains.

Comment: are you using custom auth tokens?

Comment: no I am using Firebase UI for signup & signin.

Comment: You'll need to use custom token with email set.... Only then will this rule work... Check out their documentation on custom token

Comment: do you have any link for that or any sample rule where I can get help from that sample rule ?

Answer (score 0):

So basically as i stated in comments, your rule is fine. It's just that the token needs to be a custom JWT auth token with email property set.

Take a look at the following answer to get a picture of what i am talking about

[Firebase rule auth.token.email is not working: "Simulated write denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878527/firebase-rule-auth-token-email-is-not-working-simulated-write-denied)

Also since you will be using custom token, you will need a server side script which generates this token for the email that you want. Once you have this custom token with email property set, you sign in using this token on your app and your rule will work